# REST API Woocommerce : Authentication

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to write orders in **woocommerce**

this my code :

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://example.com',
    'ck_...',
    'cs_...',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3'
          
    ]
);


// print_r($woocommerce->get('orders')); 
?>
```

**and my  Error :**

> [22-Sep-2020 10:39:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Client' not >found in /home/gbir/public_html/1/1.php:6

Answer (score 0):

Do you have A PHP wrapper for the WooCommerce REST API installed ?
It is called automattic/woocommerce.